# Skip corrupted archives in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop2, presto

Is there any way to skip processing of corrupted archive data files attached as external table in hive (or in Presto)?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you referring to skip data files or mal-formed records in the file?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for that.  Philosophical Presto has a policy of returning fully correct answers and it is impossible to tell the difference between a Presto bug and a corrupt file, so it is safer to fail the query.  I would suggest you remove the corrupt files.

Comment: @Lakshman Battini not record is mal-formed, but some of thousands of gzip (with data) could not be extracted. Check sum problem.